# How can I shrink/compress a gaussian survival function based on two or more datapoints?

Tags: normal-distribution, survival, fitting, curve-fitting, scipy

I have some data that I have fitted with a normal distribution using scipy. Here's how the fit looks like (whether it is a good fit or not is not a problem here)

```
import scipy
plt.hist(some_data, bins = 100, alpha = 0.5, normed = True)
x = np.linspace(0, 120,num=100)
r_loc, r_scale = scipy.stats.norm.fit(some_data)
plt.plot(x, scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, loc=r_loc, scale=r_scale))
```

[image]

Then, I can easily plot the survival function which looks like this

```
x = np.linspace(20, 120,num=100)
plt.plot(x, scipy.stats.norm.sf(x, loc = r_loc, scale = r_scale))
```

[image]

My question now is, how could I shrink or fit this survival function knowing that I know a few data points of interest. For instance:

1st data point: x = 40, y = 0.10
2nd data point: x = 50, y = 0.07

How could I best shrink my survival function to better fit this data points?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very unclear; what is the x = 40, y = 0.10 refer to? Do you mean you know that the survival probability at time 40 is equal to 0.10? If so, then knowing two such data points of the survival curve means you have perfectly described your normal survival function, and you can throw away your raw data, as it is now worthless. If that's not the case (which I assume), then I have no idea what x = 50, y = 0.1 refers to.